# PHP in_array weird behaviour

Tags: php, arrays

I have an issue with an `in_array` element I am utilizing in a darts point script.

Brief explanation of what goes wrong. I use an in_array to check for a re-occurrence for the same player in a darts 'single game'. if one player plays multiple single games, only the first one should give the player points for individual ranking.

Somehow it does that check in reverse ([check linked image](http://149.210.139.155/~dfk/tmp/inarray/matchform_inarray_mess2.png) for reference(sorry for bad paint edit :) )) yellow is current result, green is how it should be. the middle 4 don't count as they are double's.

**image:**
[In array diagram http://149.210.139.155/~dfk/tmp/inarray/matchform_inarray_mess2.png](http://149.210.139.155/~dfk/tmp/inarray/matchform_inarray_mess2.png)

The `in_array` is nested in a while loop so I do not understand where this behaviour is coming from.

**in_array code:**

```
//calculate indiv points
//Player TeamA
if(!in_array($scoresheet[$f_locA][$m_id], $IndivTeamA)){
$scoreA = $scoresheet[$f_locA][$m_po] . "-" . $scoresheet[$f_locB][$m_po];
$IndivTeamA[$scoresheet[$f_locA][$m_id]][rowid] = $scoresheet[$f_locA]       [$r_id];
$IndivTeamA[$scoresheet[$f_locA][$m_id]][points] =     GetIndivScore($scoreA,$BestOf);
}
//Player TeamB
if(!in_array($scoresheet[$f_locB][$m_id], $IndivTeamB)){
$scoreB = $scoresheet[$f_locB][$m_po] . "-" . $scoresheet[$f_locA][$m_po];
$IndivTeamB[$scoresheet[$f_locB][$m_id]][rowid] = $scoresheet[$f_locB][$r_id];
$IndivTeamB[$scoresheet[$f_locB][$m_id]][points] = GetIndivScore($scoreB,$BestOf);
}
```

[All relevant code](http://149.210.139.155/~dfk/tmp/inarray/inarrayrelcode.txt)

If someone can please inform me what either i have done wrong or why this behavious is this way. I cannot find any information about it here or on google. i already lost 3 hours on this.

I would not expect this to be possible since the while loop generates each row starting with row 1, thus it would be impossible (for my logic atleast), that the latest row is already in the array when php still needs to generate it.

Thanks in advance for your efforts to help me out and my appologies if i made a stupid mistake.

EDIT: [VAR_DUMP](http://149.210.139.155/~dfk/tmp/inarray/vardump.txt) & added row id's to image

Comment: Do you want the `in_array` to return just the first game value? As in if a team member appears more than once, you have said nothing to `in_array` as to which value to keep. It would be useful to get a `var_dump` of your array as well as check that your `if` statement is actually negated with `!`, so regarding your question I think what we want to see is the `else` statement that corresponds to the `If`s you've declared.

Comment: Hi Martin, thx for your reply. I indeed want just the first iteration of a game value(points and row_id) to be saved for each player. There is no else statement used on the if statements. The Link 'All relevant code' has code snipped out where the repeated dots are located.All other code is there.

If the user is not in the array allready, it gets the score for TeamA & TeamB player from that leg, sends it to a funcion wich return the points for that leg score. So if the user is allready in the array, nothing happens. This is why i do not understand how the latest value ends up in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is now fixed, and related to the fact that i was using `in_array` for a multidimensional array, wich is not supported.

Since the original if not statement would build the array in question i could not fix it by implementing a `foreach` loop. I simply added a new array with just the user ID's to fix the problem.

```
        if(!in_array($scoresheet[$f_locA][$m_id], $PlayerIndivA)){
            $scoreA = $scoresheet[$f_locA][$m_po] . "-" . $scoresheet[$f_locB][$m_po];
            $IndivTeamA[$scoresheet[$f_locA][$m_id]][rowid] = $scoresheet[$f_locA][$r_id];
            $IndivTeamA[$scoresheet[$f_locA][$m_id]][points] = GetIndivScore($scoreA,$BestOf);
            $PlayerIndivA[] = $scoresheet[$f_locA][$m_id];
        }

        if(!in_array($scoresheet[$f_locB][$m_id], $PlayerIndivB)){
            $scoreB = $scoresheet[$f_locB][$m_po] . "-" . $scoresheet[$f_locA][$m_po];
            $IndivTeamB[$scoresheet[$f_locB][$m_id]][rowid] = $scoresheet[$f_locB][$r_id];
            $IndivTeamB[$scoresheet[$f_locB][$m_id]][points] = GetIndivScore($scoreB,$BestOf);
            $PlayerIndivB[] = $scoresheet[$f_locB][$m_id];
        }
```

The solution was provided by Sneezydevil from tweakers.net (where i allso posted this).

Answer (score 0):

`in_array` searches for a value, you are using the key here. Use `array_key_exists` instead.

The in_array you use finds the following **value** inside the array.

```
in_array($scoresheet[$f_locA][$m_id], $PlayerIndivA)
```

However you assign the value of

```
$scoresheet[$f_locA][$r_id];
```

See the difference in **$m_id** and **$r_id**.

Comment: Sorry, this is not true. I am searching for value, not key. Thx for trying to help out though.

Comment: Yes, this is as designed. r_id is the row_id from the database, m_id is the member_id. Since m_id is not unique on the form(and db) but needs to be used to identify reoccurences, the r_id is saved instead so the individual score is saved on the correct row in the database.